# Application does not supported by mobile device

Tags: android, google-play

My application is available in Android market and supported Android version 2.2+. But when i open Android market using Samsung  SPH-M820 device. It doesn't show application in there. But when i enter full url and try to download app, It shows error message "app not compatible with your device". While device specifications are [here](http://dadb.net/index.php?m=specs&id=2836&c=samsung_sph-m820_galaxy_prevail).

What is the issue?

**Update: Manifest file is added:**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="packageName"
    android:installLocation="auto" 
    android:versionName="Version1" 
    android:versionCode="10">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
    <supports-screens android:smallScreens="true" 
        android:normalScreens="true" 
        android:largeScreens="true" 
        android:anyDensity="true" />

    <!-- permissions -->
    <permission android:name="packageName.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>   
    <uses-permission android:name="packageName.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <!-- This app has permission to register and receive message -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES"/>

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" android:debuggable="false">

        <receiver android:name=".PushIncidentReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
          <!-- Receive the actual message -->
          <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
              <category android:name="packageName" />
          </intent-filter>
          <!-- Receive the registration id -->
          <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
              <category android:name="packageName" />
          </intent-filter>
       </receiver>     

        <activity android:name=".SplashActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>            
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

     </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: The link is not pointing to device specifications... Or maybe it does but google translater can not translate them from korean...

Comment: Please add your manifest to your question. I guess that something in their is preventing your app to be shown as compatible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That link doesn't look like it leads to any device specifications, but rather forum boards. In addition, what we really need is your AndroidManifest.xml file. While this response doesn't answer your question directly since we don't have access to your AndroidManifest.xml, hopefully this will help guide you or others to figure out what's wrong.

You can see what devices your application supports by logging on to your developer account at http://market.android.com/publish. Choose your application, and you will see the following section on the next page underneath "Publishing options":[image]

That shows you requirements you have set up in the AndroidManifest.xml file of your application. In addition, you can even click "Show devices," and you will see a list of supported and unsupported devices for your application, such as the following:[image]

You can see that my application doesn't support two HTC phones. In addition, you can even prevent specific phones that do meet your requirements by choosing to exclude them in the list.

If you want your application to work on a specific phone, you will have to modify your AndroidManifest.xml or application itself to have more lenient requirements so your phone can satisfy them.